# AWS S3 downloader out of memory

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I'm having a problem downloading large files from an AWS S3 bucket using the golang client, I'm not an expert with golang so I would appreciate any help.

I'm creating a simple API that expose an endpoint using gin-gonic framework, when someone sends a request to that endpoint the app download a huge CSV file from an AWS S3 bucket and save the contents of the file in a local DB.

When the file size is 200 mb it works correctly but with bigger files, say 500 mb, I start getting out of memory errors.

I'm using this portion of code to create the session and donwload the file:

```
sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String("us-west-2")},
)

downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)

getInput := &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("the bucket name"),
    Key:    aws.String("the file path"),
}

buff := new(aws.WriteAtBuffer)

_, err := downloader.Download(buff, getInput)

if err != nil {    
        return nil, errors.New(err, "error downloading file")
}

return buff.Bytes(), nil
```

After this part I have a service that receive the bytes and iterate over the file contents using the golang CSV reader:

```
csv.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(theBytes))
```

The problem appears when downloading the file contents before the reader receive the bytes.

This is the stack trace I'm getting:

```
09:28:04.390    github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Engine).Run(0xc000318f00, 0xc00060ff68, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/gin.go:301 +0x14a
09:28:04.389    net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe(0xc00017c000, 0xc00017c000, 0xc00060ff08)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2866 +0xb7
09:28:04.388    net/http.(*Server).Serve(0xc00017c000, 0x13512c0, 0xc000122780, 0x0, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2937 +0x266
09:28:04.387    net.(*netFD).accept(0xc0001a9000, 0x173d6ba672b673f9, 0x0, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:172 +0x45
09:28:04.387    net.(*TCPListener).accept(0xc000122780, 0x6061c7c9, 0xc00046dd28, 0x4d5286)
/usr/local/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:139 +0x32
09:28:04.387    net.(*TCPListener).Accept(0xc000122780, 0xc00046dd78, 0x18, 0xc000000180, 0x70beec)
/usr/local/go/src/net/tcpsock.go:261 +0x65
09:28:04.385    internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc0001a9018, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1170293)
/usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:87 +0x45
09:28:04.385    internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(...)
/usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:92
09:28:04.385    internal/poll.(*FD).Accept(0xc0001a9000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:394 +0x1fc
09:28:04.384    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager.(*downloader).tryDownloadChunk(0xc000399b00, 0xc0008be280, 0x133c320, 0xc000174300, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.37.7/service/s3/s3manager/download.go:463 +0x189 fp=0xc0008bbe28 sp=0xc0008bbd80 pc=0xe48409
09:28:04.384    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager.(*downloader).downloadChunk(0xc000399b00, 0x133c160, 0xc000dd0a50, 0x1c700000, 0x500000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.37.7/service/s3/s3manager/download.go:424 +0x236 fp=0xc0008bbee8 sp=0xc0008bbe28 pc=0xe480d6
09:28:04.384    runtime.goexit()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374 +0x1 fp=0xc0008bbfd8 sp=0xc0008bbfd0 pc=0x471461
09:28:04.384    internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7f5414dee788, 0x72, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:222 +0x55
09:28:04.384    io.copyBuffer(0x133c320, 0xc000174300, 0x133d9c0, 0xc000088080, 0xc00088e000, 0x8000, 0x8000, 0xc000b52d80, 0x0, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:411 +0x206 fp=0xc0008bbd80 sp=0xc0008bbd08 pc=0x47ea66
09:28:04.384    io.Copy(...)
/usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:368
09:28:04.384    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager.(*downloader).downloadPart(0xc000399b00, 0xc000d98000)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.37.7/service/s3/s3manager/download.go:373 +0x14d fp=0xc0008bbfd0 sp=0xc0008bbee8 pc=0xe47b6d
09:28:04.384    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager.(*dlchunk).Write(0xc000174300, 0xc00088e000, 0x400, 0x8000, 0x400, 0x0, 0x0)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.37.7/service/s3/s3manager/download.go:583 +0x72 fp=0xc0008bbd08 sp=0xc0008bbcb8 pc=0xe48d72
09:28:04.384    created by github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager.(*downloader).download
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.37.7/service/s3/s3manager/download.go:317 +0x1f4
09:28:04.384    goroutine 1 [IO wait]:
09:28:04.383    runtime.sysMap(0xc0e0000000, 0x20000000, 0x19edcb8)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mem_linux.go:169 +0xc6
09:28:04.383    runtime.(*mheap).allocSpan(0x19d23a0, 0xe385, 0x400100, 0x19edcc8, 0xffffffff00000001)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1160 +0x6b6
09:28:04.383    runtime.systemstack(0x46f554)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:370 +0x66
09:28:04.383    runtime.mallocgc(0x1c7095fb, 0xfa59e0, 0x1, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1070 +0x938 fp=0xc0008bbc20 sp=0xc0008bbb80 pc=0x40fab8
09:28:04.383    runtime.makeslice(0xfa59e0, 0x1c7095fb, 0x1c7095fb, 0xc0aa006000)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:98 +0x6c fp=0xc0008bbc50 sp=0xc0008bbc20 pc=0x45056c
09:28:04.383    runtime.throw(0x1180cb4, 0x16)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1116 +0x72
09:28:04.383    runtime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:907 +0x65
09:28:04.383    runtime.(*mheap).alloc(0x19d23a0, 0xe385, 0xc0008b0101, 0x19b9ca0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:901 +0x85
09:28:04.383    runtime.mstart()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1116
09:28:04.383    runtime.systemstack_switch()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:330 fp=0xc0008bbb80 sp=0xc0008bbb78 pc=0x46f680
09:28:04.383    runtime.(*mheap).sysAlloc(0x19d23a0, 0x1c800000, 0x42da97, 0x19d23a8)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:727 +0x1e5
09:28:04.383    runtime.(*mheap).grow(0x19d23a0, 0xe385, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1344 +0x85
09:28:04.383    runtime.largeAlloc(0x1c7095fb, 0xc0008b0101, 0x6)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1177 +0x92
09:28:04.383    runtime.mallocgc.func1()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1071 +0x46
09:28:04.383    goroutine 225306 [running]:
09:28:04.383    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws.(*WriteAtBuffer).WriteAt(0xc000dd0a50, 0xc00088e000, 0x400, 0x8000, 0x1c7091fb, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.37.7/aws/types.go:193 +0x105 fp=0xc0008bbcb8 sp=0xc0008bbc50 pc=0xd18445
09:28:04.382    runtime stack:
09:28:04.379    fatal error: runtime: out of memory
```

My question is if there is any way to solve this using a different approach to download the file in the code (with different settings on the downloader maybe) or... on the contrary, if I need to split the file contents in the bucket to reduce the size and download the file by parts.

Another option could be to increase the memory that golang uses when the app is running.

I don't know which could be the best solution in my case, what do you recommend?

I appreciate any suggestion or recommendation, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do not read the whole file into memory and process it then, process is _while_ reading, line by line.

Comment: How can I do that, can you give me some hint? because the downloader returns the whole bytes of the file and then I read the bytes, I don't understand how can I process the fille contents while the bytes are still downloading.

Comment: How about just downloading it to a temporary file rather than into memory?

Comment: @JimB yes I think about that option too, but I suppose that the downloader will be the same, I mean, the portion of code to download the file bytes will be the same and I will receive the same error, in other words, the AWS downloader needs to have the whole file in memory, is that correct? or maybe I'm confused.

Comment: @AndrewSullivan: I doubt that the `downloader.Download` would buffer the entire payload when the first argument is specifically an `io.WriterAt`. The point of a function taking a writer argument is so that it _doesn't_ need to buffer all the data.

Comment: @JimB ok now I understand better, so if I save the bytes to a temporal file, will I get the same error from the IO api in golang? I mean.. when I try to read the file from the file system

Comment: I don't know what the _"error from the IO api in golang"_ is, but if you don't load the entire thing into memory, then you should not have the same problem causing you to run out of memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `downloader` you are unable to process the file while it is downloading: it downloads different chunks concurrently so you do not receive the bytes in order.

If you want to process the bytes as you download them, you can try using `s3.S3` instead. This downloads the object in order, but only uses a single goroutine so will be slower.

Something like:

```golang
    sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-west-2")},
    )

    s3Client := s3.New(sess)

    getInput := &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("the bucket name"),
        Key:    aws.String("the file path"),
    }

    resp, err := s3Client.GetObjectWithContext(context.TODO(), getInput)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error downloading file: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    rd := csv.NewReader(resp.Body)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will test this approach to see if it works. I have a question: I do not understand how the reader would read the body (resp.Body) if it does not yet have the full bytes of the file, if I'm not missing something that's the idea with this approach right?

Comment: Hi, yes you have the correct idea.

If you look at the `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` interface you will see that you call Read with a byte slice. The size of the byte slice may be much smaller than the file you are trying to download, meaning you need multiple Read calls to get the whole file.

This allows the file to be processed in chunks without having to have the whole file in memory. You can think of the GetObjectWithContext call as starting a new goroutine which fills up the byte slices passed to the Read calls.